# ColdFusion MX7 - Cached JDBC Driver

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, coldfusion

I receive this error every time I try to call the proc below. No matter what values I pass in, the error is the same. Is it possible that the DB driver is caching the request/response? Both the web server and the database server have been completely restarted, and still, this error.

> **Error Executing Database Query.**
>
> `[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]The conversion of the 
>   varchar value '9996663333' overflowed an int column.`
>
> The error occurred in
>   E:\Inetpub\wwwroot##redacted##\htdocs\eSignature\index.cfm: line 14
>
> - Called from
>     E:\Inetpub\wwwroot##redacted##\htdocs\eSignature\application.cfc:
>     line 72
> - Called from
>     E:\Inetpub\wwwroot##redacted##\htdocs\eSignature\index.cfm: line 14
> - Called from
>     E:\Inetpub\wwwroot##redacted##\htdocs\eSignature\application.cfc:
>     line 72
>
> 12 :
>   13 :  <cfquery name="insertSign"
>   datasource="#application.eSignatureDB#">
>   14 :      EXEC
>   procInsertCaseESignatureStatusScrubbing   @CaseNo = '#caseID#', @Status
>   = '#event#', @EmailURLCode = '#code#' 
>   15 :  </cfquery>
>  
>   16 :  **SQL** EXEC procInsertCaseESignatureStatusScrubbing    @CaseNo = '54321', @Status = '2', @EmailURLCode = 'asdfqwad'
>
> **DATASOURCE**      eSignatureTest
>   **VENDORERRORCODE**     248 SQLSTATE    22003

Comment: What happens when you try to use the cfstoredproc, and cfstoredproc param than direct EXEC?

Comment: What's the result when executed directly in the db with those values?

Comment: An `int` datatype is -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647). The value you are trying to insert won't fit into an `int`. Where is that value coming from? What does your stored procedure look like?

Comment: I just solved this late last night - cfadministrator on the server was mapped to a different server, so the datasource change I expected to occur didn't. I still don't understand why I repeatedly received this same error, despite passing different values into the proc. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Depends on where that value is coming from. If it's something *inside* the procedure (variable, record within a table, ...) it might occur no matter what parameters are passed in. That has nothing to do with CF. It's the procedure and/or data itself.